# fullcalendar data from json object

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I load json from a php file but the json contains other data. The events are placed in the 'fullcalendar' object but i do not know how i can select the data.

I load current the data with this code, can someone point me in the right direction?

Greathings Christophe VD

```
    $('#Agenda').fullCalendar({
        lang: 'nl',
        height: "parent",
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: {
            url: json_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                actie: "GetList"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                return data.fullCalendar;
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Systeemfout.');
            }
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {                             
            var huur_id = calEvent.id;
            weergave(huur_id);
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            var label = date.format("d-MM-YYYY");
        }
    })
```

Comment: Didn't understand your requirement. Could you please elaborate more

Comment: if you're not directly returning events in the format required by fullCalendar then you'll need to use [this syntax](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) for declaring the "events" property instead. Then you use the provided callback function to return the relevant data to fullCalendar. Alternatively, if you want to stick with the current JavaScript code, make your server just return a flat array of events, instead of an object which then contains an array in a sub-property. Then fullCalendar will detect it automatically and you can remove your "success" callback entirely.

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks that did the job. i had try it but it was a white background with white text color so it was empty.